# How to search vector layer features in Mapbox GL JS

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js

I need to add a search bar that will search vector layer attribute features which are hosted by mapbox. I'm using the Mapbox GL JS API. I know this can be done fairly easily with Mapbox js/Leaflet. I'm totally stuck as to how to do the same in Mapbox GL JS. I want to search for a zip code, which corresponds to a feature attribute in my vector layer (please note, I don't wish to geocode an address or zip code. I am aware that there is a geocoder plugin for Mapbox GL. This is not what I'm looking for). I'm then hoping to update a html info panel with various feature values from the vector layer based on the matching search entry.

I need to know how to marry search functionality with the vector layer features served by Mapbox (This question specifically relates to Mapbox GL, not the older Mapbox JS library).

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in search functionality in mapbox-gl-js.

You can implement this functionality by

- getting a list of all visible features using the `featuresIn` method ([docs](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#Map.featuresIn), [example](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/using-featuresin/)) OR using the original GeoJSON containing those features
- filtering those features using custom logic

Comment: side note: it appears all layers for the active map (mapbox-gl-js v0.15) are available on `<map>.style._layers`. I'm not aware of any other method for accessing *all* layers. Am guessing `featuresIn` and `featuresAt` is best for scenarios that have a point or bounds.

Comment: The standard way to access all layers is `map.getStyle().layers`